# How can I obtain concurrent deletes for this table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, concurrency, blocking

We have a program that is currently doing something to the effect of:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE [Source].[dbo].[SourceTable]
SET [ProcessedOn] = GETDATE()
OUTPUT DELETED.* -- Output is captured via bcp
WHERE [Source] = 0
AND [Destination] = @Destination

-- Bulk copy from Source to SourceHistory via SqlBulkCopy using:
-- SELECT * FROM [Source].[dbo].[SourceTable]
-- WHERE [Source] = 0
-- AND [Destination] = @Destination

DELETE FROM [Source].[dbo].[SourceTable]
WHERE [Source] = 0
AND [Destination] = @Destination

COMMIT
```

We have multiple clients that execute this code against a central server. Each is executing with a unique `@Destination` variable.

The `SourceTable` has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable]
(
    [Source]        int       NOT NULL,
    [Destination]   int       NOT NULL,
    [SourceTableId] bigint    NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Data]          int       NOT NULL,
    -- Other related "data" fields
    [ProcessedOn]   datetime2     NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Source], [Destination], [SourceTableId])
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Our issue is that we are, as we might expect, running into process blocking between clients that are executing these queries.

Is there anything we can do to minimize blocking between distinct clients? Each client will **always** execute with a unique `@Destination`. We have the transaction in place not to prevent two clients from updating the same data, but to allow rolling back an individual client if an unexpected error occurs.

Comment: Pretty sure you *want* blocking in this scenario. But I'm not sure I understand the process here. Within one transaction you update all the matching rows, then copy them into a history table, then delete them? Why not delete them with OUTPUT to the history table? Why does BCP get involved here at all? Why update rows you're about to delete?

Comment: BCP is used to output the data for the clients to use. The `UPDATE` is used to mark when the rows have been processed. Data is moving into history for historical purposes and then purged from the source. The history is append-only, the source is the one that's deleted not the history. The idea is to take a data set, output it in bulk format, add auditing information (`ProcessedOn = GETDATE()`), and move it from a transient database into a historical database.

Comment: I'm with Aaron, sounds like you definitely want blocking on this one.  But to your concern, you think there may be more blocking than just row locking?  How many rows would a client be deleting in a single batch?  I don't recall where the tipping point is exactly, but if there are enough deletes occurring in a single batch the entire table gets locked.  Maybe consider batching the deletes to minimize if this is the case.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli: This model is used for a few different tables. We have anywhere from a couple hundred rows (no real blocking since transaction takes a few milliseconds) to millions of rows. Each client touches completely orthogonal subsets of data.

Comment: Mike, check out this article on lock escalation.  Again batching can help resolve some of this. [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @SteveMangiameli: Thanks, I'll take a look.